# wp_mail wordpress html with style not aplying

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, html-email

I'm trying to send mail from my wordpress plugin but when I retrieve it, it has not styles or images.

I'm doing this way:

```
<?php
$headers = array(
    "From: Enara <no-reply@enara.es>",
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'"
);
$message = "<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='background-color: #16a085;'>
            <table>
                <tr><td colspan='2'><img style=\'margin-botton: 20px;\' src='http://enara.litrodeenergia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/enara-white.png' /></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan='2'>DATOS DE CLIENTE</td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan='2'>$particular</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre:</td>
                    <td>$nombre<br></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apellidos:</td>
                    <td>$apellidos</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nif:</td>
                    <td>$nif</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tel&eacute;fono:</td>
                    <td>$telefono</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>";

$result = new stdClass();
$result->mailOk = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I tried a style code in my head, delete the html/head/body blocks (only send the div html code), changed the content-type to `iso`, and made the wp filter `wp_mail_content_type` 'text/html'.

The image don't work also.

If I debug the recieved email  with devtools, I see:

```
<div style="background-color:#16a085">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="http://enara.litrodeenergia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/enara-white.png" style=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">DATOS DE CLIENTE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Usuario particular</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre:</td>
        <td>afsd<br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apellidos:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nif:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Teléfono:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the email headers:

```
Received: from server
Received: from 
Subject: Formulario Alta Usuario Web
X-PHP-Script: 
Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 11:07:52 +0000
From: 
Message-ID: <53692f88fe04a71fd41ca2475611fa99@
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8'"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - 
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - 
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [500 495] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - 
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: 
X-Authenticated-Sender: 
X-Source: /usr/bin/php
X-Source-Args: /usr/bin/php /home/public_html/
X-Source-Dir: litrodeenergia.com:/public_html/
Return-Path: 
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: IPOnAllowList
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
```

Comment: why do you need to add the backslash in this? `style=\'margin-botton: 20px;\'` should be `style='margin-botton: 20px;'`

Comment: It was a test, it doesn't workt without the \

Comment: Logically, if you use `"` for the echo string, you'd have to escape double quotes with a backslash, however, a single quote `'` wouldn't need escaping...

Comment: I know... in fact, on the style  tang in div you don't see \. This is a test, by desesperation :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be better if you put the code how did you use `wp_mail_content_type`

You should filter content type before call **wp_mail()** For example:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {
            return 'text/html';
});

wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', '<div>The message</div>' );
```

Comment: Wow! Need this filter only on production machine, on local was working ok my html... strange, but, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
```

Seems by default `wp_mail()` returns `text/plain` content.

> You can use WordPress’s wp_mail() function to send emails from your WordPress site. However, the default content type is ‘text/plain’ which does not allow using HTML. If you want to send HTML emails then you will need to set the content type of the email to “text/html” by using the ‘wp_mail_content_type’ filter.

Source: [How to Send HTML Emails From WordPress](http://www.wordpresscheatsheets.com/how-to-send-html-emails-from-wordpress-using-wp_mail-function)

**Edit**

Issue seems to be related to mail client rendering of HTML content.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I had tested this filter, but I get same result.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Can you inspect the mail with devtools to check the output? Also check the headers in the received e-mail

Comment: Output in devtools: <div style="background-color:#16a085">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><img src="http://enara.litrodeenergia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/enara-white.png" style=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">DATOS DE CLIENTE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Usuario particular</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nombre:</td>
<td>afsd<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apellidos:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nif:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Teléfono:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

Comment: Received: from server.enara-energia.es (107.6.177.82) by correo.extrasoft.es
 (10.150.5.7) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 8.3.213.0; Tue, 23 Feb 2016
 12:07:53 +0100
Received: from enara by server.enara-energia.es with local (Exim 4.86)
 (envelope-from <enara@server.enara-energia.es>) id 1aYAoq-0005OM-Sq for
From: Enara <no-reply@enara.es>
Message-ID: <53692f88fe04a71fd41ca2475611fa99@enara.litrodeenergia.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8'"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: you could add this to the original question or post as images, also please edit out any personal/identifying info.... Anyway, the e-mail is getting the HTML content type so that's fine, problem could be with the CSS rules, can you play around with the values using the inspector and check whether or not the CSS is applied

Comment: Original edited. Anyway, I'm seeing that in outlook I don't see styles and images, but sending mail to a gmail account and reading it by web, I see the css styles applyied (but the mail goes to spam)

Comment: Ah. Do you think it can be a problem with the mail client? Check [this article](http://www.verticalresponse.com/blog/its-not-you-its-outlook-the-complete-guide-for-email-marketers/) about Outlook e-mail

Comment: It seems like outlook is annoying me, then. (And gmail's spam filter too)

Comment: Yeah, Outlook allows minimal CSS styles (no backgrounds, no positioning) . As for Gmail spam filter - check this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126