# Wordpress reset password email - Plain Text to HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, email, wordpress-login

I need help with the below script

```
public function replace_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {
    // Create new message
    $msg  = __( 'Hello!', 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= sprintf( __( 'You asked us to reset your password for your account using the email address %s.', 'personalize-login' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __( "If this was a mistake, or you didn't ask for a password reset, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.", 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __( 'To reset your password, visit the following address:', 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __( 'Thanks!', 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n";

    return $msg;
}
```

This is replacing the **Wordpress reset password email**. It functions great and is working a treat. However, it is not very pretty and I want to replace it with an `HTML` email.

Is there a way that I can add `HTML` to this and still keep the function of **printing the URL and user email address**? For example;

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>You asked us to reset your password for your account using the email address <?php PRINT USER EMAIL ?></p>
  <a href="<?php PRINT URL ?></a>
</div>
```

I know that the above is very basic and the `PHP` is not correct but if I wanted to replace the `Plain Text` email with this, how would I do it? Is it perhaps possible to create a separate `PHP` file with the `HTML` content and  `return` the content from this template?

Your time is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp\_mail wordpress html with style not aplying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575306/wp-mail-wordpress-html-with-style-not-aplying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question was done in two parts

First was to add to the `functions.php`

```
function email_set_content_type(){
return "text/html";
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','email_set_content_type' );
```

Second is added within a custom plugin as shown below

```
    $msg  = __( "<div><h1>Hello!</h1>", 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg  = __( "<p>You asked us to reset your password for your account using the email address", 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= sprintf( __( "%s.</p>", 'personalize-login' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __( "<a href='", 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user_login ), 'login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __( "'></a></div>", 'personalize-login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";

    return $msg;
```

I have now used this method to replace all core Wordpress Messages with entire `email` templates, including `html` `body` and `head` tags.

Thank you for those who had an input into my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Darren Mathers, you can use something like that

```
function replace_retrieve_password_message($message, $key, $user_login,   $user_data) {
// Create new message

  $msg  = '<div><h1>Hello!, personalize-login</h1>';
  $msg .= '<p>You asked us to reset your password for your account using the email address personalize-login </p>'.$user_login;
  $msg .= "<p>If this was a mistake, or you didn't ask for a password reset, just ignore this email and nothing will happen personalize-login";
  $msg .= '<p> To reset your password, visit the following address: personalize-login';

  $msg .= '<p>'.site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=".rawurlencode($user_login),'login').'</p>' 
  $msg .= '<p>Thanks! personalize-login</p> </div>';

  return $msg;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this but it is breaking the plugin. Any other suggestions?

Comment: which plugins you are using please mention the name here

Comment: user this in function.php add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function() { return 'text/html'; });

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I will post the answer to my solution below and yes you are correct 'wp_mail_content_type' was required.